# tkinter focus_set() not setting focus

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, focus, setfocus

I am trying to set focus on an entry window however I get an error throw every time.

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'focus_set'`

I looked up some examples of this and none of the suggestions worked. I'm assuming I have an error from naming something in my code if the function is just flat out not working.

Here is my code...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def greet():
    print(f"Hello, {user_name.get() or 'World'}!")


root = tk.Tk()

user_name = tk.StringVar()

name_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Name: ").pack(side="left", padx=(0, 10))
name_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=user_name).pack(side="left")

name_entry.focus_set()

greet_button = ttk.Button(root, text="greet", command=greet).pack(side="left")

quit_button = ttk.Button(root, text="quit", command=root.destroy).pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

I am normally develop we applications in JavaScript so python is a little unfamiliar to me, I am just trying to learn something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer but I don't know why it works. If i put pack on another line it works...

```
name_label = ttk.Label(root, text="Name: ").pack(side="left", padx=(0, 10))
name_entry = ttk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=user_name)
name_entry.pack(side="left")
name_entry.focus()
```

Comment: This works because the geometry manager methods `pack`, `place`, and `grid` all return `None`. So if you use `name_entry = ttk.Entry(...).pack()`, `name_entry` evaluates to `None`, but if you put `pack` on a separate line then `name_entry` will evaluate to the instance of `ttk.Entry` which is what you actually want.